# Can I disable/enable shutdown, logoff, restart buttons in start menu through an application or command? If yes then how?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, console-application

I need to write an application that can disable shutdown, logoff, restart buttons and does some work and before terminating it again enables all these buttons.

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried?  Do you have any code to show?

Comment: yes, i have code to do it through regedit,,,,

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <Winerror.h>

int main()
{
    HKEY Regkey,RegSubkey ; 
    DWORD buf = 1 ;
    DWORD Disposition ;
    LONG ret ;

    ret = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer"),0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&Regkey) ;

    if(ret !=  ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("RegOpenKeyEx failed......%d\n",GetLastError()) ;
        getchar() ;
        return 0 ;
    }
    else
        printf("RegOpenKeyEx success......\n") ;

    ret = RegSetValueEx(Regkey,TEXT("NoClose"),0,REG_DWORD,(const BYTE*)&buf,sizeof(buf)) ;
    if(ret !=  ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("RegSetValueEx failed......%d\n",GetLastError()) ;
        getchar() ;
        return 0 ;
    }
    else
        printf("RegSetValueEx success......\n") ;

    //getchar() ;
    RegCloseKey(Regkey) ;
    return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: Run the .exe file generated by executing this code with "Run as Administrator".

Comment: This code is for disabling shutdown and restart buttons from start menu.

Comment: Is there a specific registry key if I want to remove "Shutdown" but NOT "Restart" or anything else?